# For statement not working as expected

Tags: javascript, for-loop

not too experienced programmer here.

Long story short, I am trying to make a small solar system type thing, and when the mass of the star plus the mass of the planet is larger or equal to the distance of the planet to the center of the star divided by 2, the planet is supposed to fall into the star.

```
for(i = 0; i < planetamount; i++){
    if((starmass+planetmass[i]) >= (initialradius/2)){
        radius[i]--;
    }
}
```

In this case, planetamount equals to 1, as I have only one planet. The array brackets with the variable i in them are to indicate which planet's data it is taking (only one available, planet 0). Now, the weird part.

```
starmass = 100;
planetmass = [10];
radius = [150];
initialradius = radius[0];
```

So then, let's check;

```
starmass + planetmass = 100 + 10 = 110
initialradius/2 = 150/2 = 75
```

As we can obviously see, 110 is larger than or equal to 75 (in this case larger than), yet the planet doesn't fall into the star (and yes, it is a continuously updated canvas animation, so it is supposed to work, which it did before for some reason). The value of radius[0] just doesn't change.
Maybe the info that this for-loop is in a requestAnimationFrame() function might help.

I really hope this isn't too confusing (which it probably is), but if anyone could give me a simple answer, that would be great.

-JReesW

Comment: To anyone who came here just before an edit, I had the values of 75 and 110 in the first line after the third cole block mixed up, the problem is still there btw.

Comment: I'd suggest opening your console (hit F12) then add `console.log(starmass, planetmass[i], initialradius)`. This will show you their *actual* values and you can get an idea of what's wrong.

Comment: A [basic test](https://jsfiddle.net/xb4qgk2z/) works, so I'd need to see the live example to figure out more.

Comment: @MikeC I did this, it for some reason just gives me the starmass and initialradius as their correct values, but planetmass[i] is undefined. Entering console.log(i) gives 1

Comment: @JReesW Remember that arrays are zero-indexed. So you need to make sure you're accessing `planetmass[0]`. Also, when `undefined` is converted to a number it's `0`. That's why the calculation seems wrong.

Comment: And what is the expected radius[i] value per your calculation?

Comment: I know this, and that's why var i should never be higher than 1 due to (i < planetamount), but even when undefined equals to zero, the starmass (100) is still larger than half of the initialradius (150/2 = 75).

Comment: @AlexBell the i value should be 0, so then the radius should first be 150, which would be reduced by 1 everytime the function loops using window.requestAnimationFrame(Update). Update is the name of my function btw

Comment: Then please post the entire code snippet related to this issue including that window.requestAnimationFrame(Update) etc. Thanks and regards,

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/JReesW/57jwrgwe/1/ please note that there are some prompts. Please enter "blue", then "big", then "close". This gives a scenario in which the planet should fall into the star. Also please ignore the fact that I am noob in programming and that it could be done more efficient, so please just focus on the problem at hand. The variables start at line 21, starmass is defined at line 50, the for-loop starts at line 119 and the problem starts at line 147. Note that all of the other parts work (or are at least supposed to work)

Comment: It seems that your original question is quite misleading because the function you have reported is working just fine as expected (see my answer below). Please clarify the issue, narrow down the question (focus on the problematic part of the code rather than adding the functional spec of your project) and do the appropriate editing. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

See how many times it's iterating through the loop.

I may be wrong about your goal, but give this a go and tell me what you think:

```
for(var i = 0; i < planetamount; i++){
    if((starmass+planetmass[i]) >= (initialradius/2)){
        while(radius[i]>0) { radius[i]--; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it works, but it makes the planet's radius instantly go to 0, but what I'm trying to do is that it reduces the radius by 1, and then again by 1 after the entire function has looped by window.requestAnimationFrame(Update).

Comment: Hmm.. are you trying to make it go to 0 after a few loops?

Comment: yes, but not using the for-loop. The for-loop is just to go through all of the planets (currently only 1). It goes to 0 after a few seconds because of the window.requestAnimationFrame() that this for-loop is in.

Comment: You may never actually reach 0.. it will only decrement until starmass+planetmass = initialRadius/2

Comment: yes I know, but this isn't needed as my planet is destroyed before this using an other formula, it should however be able to fly into my star.

Comment: Did you actually test the code above? Because if it works then I would say that you are never reaching the for loop but one time.

Comment: I did, but it just set the radius to 0 in one go. The for-loop is supposed to be used only once as I only have 1 planet. The function it is in loops, which causes the slight delay which makes it animated

Comment: Well, I'd say that the function that is in that loops is only being looped once.

Comment: It is not, the function uses the requestAnimationFrame(). The function also contains the orbit of the planet, which works perfectly fine.

Comment: The newest answer indicates that the issue resides in other parts of your code. Try posting that and maybe I can help

Comment: jsfiddle.net/JReesW/57jwrgwe/1 please note that there are some prompts. Please enter "blue", then "big", then "close". This gives a scenario in which the planet should fall into the star. Also please ignore the fact that I am noob in programming and that it could be done more efficient, so please just focus on the problem at hand. The variables start at line 21, starmass is defined at line 50, the for-loop starts at line 119 and the problem starts at line 147. Note that all of the other parts work (or are at least supposed to work)

Answer (score 0):

The function itself is working just fine as expected: after the first (and only) iteration it returns the radius[0] value of 149 (i.e. 150 less 1). Following is the test snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="radius0"></p>
<script>
        starmass = 100;
        planetmass = [10];
        radius = [150];
        initialradius = radius[0];
        planetamount=1;
        function test() {
            for (i = 0; i < planetamount; i++)
            {
                if ((starmass + planetmass[i]) >= (initialradius / 2))
                {
                    radius[i]--;
                }
            }
            return radius[0];
        }
        document.getElementById("radius0").innerHTML = test();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Therefore, the issue resides in the other part of your code which you didn't include in your post.

Hope this may help.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/JReesW/57jwrgwe/1 please note that there are some prompts. Please enter "blue", then "big", then "close". This gives a scenario in which the planet should fall into the star. Also please ignore the fact that I am noob in programming and that it could be done more efficient, so please just focus on the problem at hand. The variables start at line 21, starmass is defined at line 50, the for-loop starts at line 119 and the problem starts at line 147. Note that all of the other parts work (or are at least supposed to work).

Comment: Just a quick observation: it does not seem correct to compare the mass with radius, i.e. (starmass+planetmass[i]) >= (initialradius/2)

Comment: I know, but I had to think of something, and this seemed to work until I added the array part and the for-loop for multiple planets. Using this formula, if the planet and star were large enough and the planet was close enough, it would just start flying into the star.

Comment: Sorry, but this question became a sort of "Russian doll question" and looks more like a request for a software development/debugging. The answer is already given to you pertinent to the original post. You can accept it or not, but at this point I am closing this discussion thread. Please post your additional questions separately. Best regards,

Comment: I will ask my father (professional PHP and JavaScript programmer) about this. Sorry for the inconvenience I may have caused and I will try to work on my question asking skills. Thank you for your help!